# pandas read dataframes in a loop and get the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I've got several dataframes with the same column size but different row size as df0:

```
lang,h,H
ar,2,2
en,1,2
es,3,4
id,4,2
```

and df1:

```
lang,h,H
ar,2,2
en,2,2
es,2,3
```

Those dataframes are .csv files stored in a directory, their names are `df + i + '.csv'`, where i goes in range(10). I would like to read all the files, and then make a mean of each columns. So far I tried the following, reading one by one:

```
df0 = pd.read_csv('df0.csv', index_col='lang')
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', index_col='lang')
```

then concat and taking the mean:

```
df = pd.concat((df0, df1), axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

which returns:

```
ar    2.00
en    1.75
es    3.00
id    3.00
dtype: float64
```

How may I read all the files stored in the directory in the loop and get the mean of the all columns in the dataframes? In this case I would like a dataframe which contains the h and H columns with their mean values.

EDIT:
This is the expected output dataframe:

```
lang,mean_h,mean_H
ar,2,2
en,1.50,2
es,2.50,3.50
id,4,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all files in a directory using glob module

```
import glob
myFiles = glob.glob('C://my_folder//*.csv')
```

loop through each file and add to tuple dfs

```
dfs = ()
for file in myFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='lang')
    dfs = dfs + tuple((df,))
```

Finally concat them and calculate mean

```
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
df = df.groupby(df.index).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns only one column and not two as the original dataframes. I'm looking for the mean over each columns (h and H in this case).

Comment: Thanks again and sorry, we're getting close to what I need, I edited my question with the expected result!

Comment: just add df.columns = ['lang', 'meanh', 'meanH']

Comment: Great thanks! Sorry there was a typo in my code! Thanks!